# Qual a razão da diferença entre a conjugação positiva e negativa nas segundas pessoas do imperativo?

Tags: verbos, origem-histórica, conjugações

No imperativo, a flexão depende de o comando, exortação, etc. ser positivo ou negativo. Exemplos:

> Tu, **vai** embora / não **vás** embora
>   Tu, **sai** daqui / não **saias** daqui
>   Tu, **apaga** a luz / não **apagues** a luz
>   Tu, **corre** / não **corras**
>   Tu, **tem** coragem / não **tenhas** medo

Também na segunda pessoa do plural:

> Vós, **ide** embora / não **vades** embora
>   Vós, **saí** daqui / não **saiais** daqui
>   Vós, **apagai** a luz / não **apagueis** a luz
>   Vós, **correi** / não **corrais**
>   Vós, **tende** coragem / não **tenhais** medo

Ok, para o plural precisei da ajuda das [tabelas de conjugações](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-ir); na negativa só tinha acertado duas. Mas na verdade a negativa é a mais fácil, porque é igual ao conjuntivo/subjuntivo.

Nas outras pessoas não há diferença entre conjugação positiva e negativa, sendo ambas iguais ao conjuntivo/subjuntivo. Creio que mais nenhum tempo ou modo tem esta diferença.

Qual a razão desta diferença entre conjugação positiva e negativa nas segundas pessoas do imperativo? Já vem do latim? No espanhol também há esta diferença, pelos menos nalguns verbos, mas no francês, não. Há alguma explicação para a igualdade entre as conjugações negativas e o conjuntivo/subjuntivo?

Comment: apagueis e tenhais? ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, senhor, não tenhais dúvidas.

Comment: Basicamente, já vem de trás: http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~struck/classes/latin309/syntax/imperative.html#neg_future

Comment: Já agora, _tabela de conjugações_? O único verbo irregular aí é _ir_ (e é único verbo em que a 2a pessoa do plural do presente do conjuntivo não é previsível sabendo tu as outras).

Comment: @Artefacto Eu vacilo um bocado na segunda pessoa do plural nalguns tempos e modos. Se tivesse pensado um bocado talvez lá tivesse chegado sozinho. Talvez. Só depois de ver as tabelas é que me lembrei, ou apercebi, que as negativas são iguais ao conjuntivo. Ti basicamente já tens o material suficiente para uma resposta. Tás à espera de quê?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O latim só tinha duas formas para o infinitivo: singular e plural.  Por isso, há duas formas do imperativo que  o português herdou do latim (usando *correr* como exemplo): **corre** (latim *curre*) e **correi** (latim *correte*).

Mas então a pergunta deve ser como o latim flexionava os verbos no imperativo negativo.  Resposta fácil: não os flexionava :-)  O latim usava o verbo *nolle* («não querer») mais infinitivo para expressar um desejo em negativo:

- **não corras** (latim **noli currere**, lit. *não queiras correr*)
- **não corrais** (latim **nolite currere**, lit. *não queirais correr*)

Como mencionas o castelhano, cabe notar que tradicionalmente estas duas formas se consideravam as únicas formas do modo imperativo.  As outras formas do imperativo evoluíram do que, em castelhano pelos menos, se chama «o conjuntivo exortativo» (*el subjuntivo exhortativo*).  Este uso do conjuntivo já não se usa tanto como no passado, mas efetivamente era o conjuntivo empregado na oração principal/ordinal.  Um uso ainda comum hoje é no *Pai nosso*:

> Santificado **seja** o Vosso Nome
>   **Venha** a nós o Vosso Reino
>   **Seja feita** a Vossa Vontade

O «mando» não é dado a Deus para santificar o seu nome, mas é dado diretamente ao nome na terceira pessoa (se nos dirigíssemos diretamente ao seu nome, diríamos «Ó Vosso Nome, sede santificado»).

Quando formas de tratamento como «A vossa alteza» e coisas assim que obrig(av)am à terceira pessoa, foi adotado aquele uso para servir como imperativo.  Mas esse uso do conjuntivo tinha uma diferença importante relativamente ao imperativo «verdadeiro»: podia-se usar na negativa facilmente: *venha algo* ou *não venha algo*.

Dali, deve ser fácil ver como as formas negativas do imperativo chegaram: o conjuntivo exortativo acabou em todas as posições que o imperativo não ocupava, é dizer, as formas negativas para o tratamento informal (tu e vós) e todas as formas para o tratamento formal (você(s)).

Comment: Muito interessante. Mas que dizes [deste link do Artefacto](http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~struck/classes/latin309/syntax/imperative.html#neg_future)? Fiquei com a ideia que mesmo no latim já se usava o conjuntivo para comandar: *cave/cave ne curras*

Comment: Ainda se usou um equivalente a *noli correre* no castelhano e no galaico-português? Atualmente, podemos dizer, *não correr*, mas soa-me até um bocado rude.