# Morfemas tempo-modo e número-pessoa do Imperativo Afirmativo?

Tags: verbos, morfema

Eu estava a ler "Morfemas do Português" escrito por Valter Kehdi que reproduz a separação das desinências verbais em morfemas de Mattoso da Câmara.
O problema é que Mattoso da Câmara não elencou a separação por morfemas Modo-Tempo e Número-Pessoa das desinências do Imperativo Afirmativo. Quero saber como seria feita essa separação?
Vou incluir abaixo uma tabela com parte to paradigma de conjugação do verbo cantar da 1ª conjugação para referência que inclui exemplos dos morfemas com alomorfes e excepções.

| Base Verbal | Vogal Temática | Modo-Tempo | Número-Pessoa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Presente do Indicativo** |  |  |  |
| cant | Ø | Ø | o |
| cant | a | Ø | s |
| cant | a | Ø | Ø |
| cant | a | Ø | mos |
| cant | a | Ø | is |
| cant | a | Ø | m |
| **Pretérito Perfeito do Indicativo** |  |  |  |
| cant | e | Ø | i |
| cant | a | Ø | ste |
| cant | o | Ø | u |
| cant | á | Ø | mos |
| cant | a | Ø | stes |
| cant | a | ra | m |
| **Presente do Conjuntivo** |  |  |  |
| cant | Ø | e | Ø |
| cant | Ø | e | s |
| cant | Ø | e | Ø |
| cant | Ø | e | mos |
| cant | Ø | e | is |
| cant | Ø | e | m |
| **Condicional** |  |  |  |
| cant | a | ria | Ø |
| cant | a | ria | s |
| cant | a | ria | Ø |
| cant | a | ría | mos |
| cant | a | ríe | is |
| cant | a | ria | m |

#### Como deveria ser feita a separação para o Imperativo Afirmativo?

| Base Verbal | Vogal Temática | Modo-Tempo | Número-Pessoa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Imperativo Afirmativo** |  |  |  |
| cant | a | Ø | Ø |
| cant | Ø | e | Ø |
| cant | Ø | e | mos |
| cant | a | Ø | i |
| cant | Ø | e | m |

Reparem **por comparação** que no pretérito perfeito do indicativo os morfemas número-pessoa são excepções ao padrão normal. Eu assumo que **os morfemas número-pessoa** da 2ª pessoa do singular e 2ª pessoa do plural do imperativo afirmativo também são excepções.

Fazendo a comparação dos **morfemas modo-tempo**, no condicional podemos ver a alomorfe tempo-modo na 2ª pessoa do plural. Mas se olharmos para o pretérito perfeito vemos que a vogal temática também muda na 1ª e 3ª pessoa do singular. Portanto eu não consigo perceber se no imperativo afirmativo o "a" e "e" são variações na vogal temática ou se são alomofores do morfema modo-tempo. Devia o morfema zero (Ø) preencher a coluna da vogal temática ou a coluna do morfema modo-tempo? (Ou devemos considerar que ocorre acumulação?)

Termino com esta citação de Valter Kehdi:

> As desinências acima ilustram, também, o fenômeno da cumulação: exprimem tempo e modo, simultaneamente, bem como número e pessoa. Algumas acumulam outros valores gramaticais: é o caso da desinência número-pessoal -o, que, por figurar apenas no presente do indicativo, passa também a ser marca desse tempo e modo.
>
> Valter Kehdi in "Morfemas do Português".

Também relevante

> Assim, temos uma formula geral da estrutura do vocâbulo
> verbal português:
>
> **T (R + VT) + SF (SMT + SNP)**
>
> A cumulação num único morfema das noções de modo e tempo
> determina evidentemente, em princípio, 13 sufixos modo-temporais.
> Só esporadicamente há neles alomorfia na base da classe mórfica,
> ou conjugação a que o verbo pertence.
> Da mesma sorte, há 6 sufixos numero-pessoais,

Segue-se este comentário que penso ser a razão pela qual o Imperativo Pessoal não é analisado no livro:

> Tambem, entre os sufixos modo-temporais, não levamos em
> conta o pouco rendimento do pretérito mais-que-perfeito, já aqui
> salientado. Nem a obsolescência da área do subjuntivo não-subordinado,
> ou imperativo, invadida pelo indicativo.
>
> Mattoso da Câmara, in "Estrutura da língua portuguesa" capítulo XIII A flexão verbal Portuguesa do padrão geral.

Comment: Olha isto é muita coisa para absorver duma só vez. Mas duas observações. De origem só havia imperativo na 2ª pessoa; as outras foram tomadas de empréstimo do conjuntivo/subjuntivo. No conjuntivo e condicional, 1ª pessoa, número-pessoa, tens "o", quando deveria ser "Ø". Deves ter feito copy e paste do presente do indicativo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É exatamente como tu propões, e não podia ser mais simples. As segundas pessoas, singular e plural, do imperativo afirmativo derivam do presente do indicativo por subtração do -*s* final:

| Modo Tempo |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Presente do Indicativo** | tu cantas | vós cantais | tu vendes | vós vendeis | tu partes | vós partis |
| **Imperativo Afirmativo** | canta | cantai | vende | vendei | parte | parti |

Logo, tal como no presente do indicativo, nas segundas pessoas do imperativo de *cantar*, tens radical *cant* + vogal temática *a*. A desinência pessoa-número no presente do indicativo é *s* na 2ª pessoa do singular, desaparece no imperativo; é *is* na 2ª do plural, fica só *i* no imperativo.

Estas são as únicas formas próprias do imperativo (ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3620/qual-a-raz%C3%A3o-da-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-a-conjuga%C3%A7%C3%A3o-positiva-e-negativa-nas-segundas-pe) sobre o assunto). As restantes do afirmativo ― 3ª do singular e 1ª e 3ª do plural ― e todas do negativo foram tomadas de empréstimo do presente do conjuntivo (subjuntivo no Brasil). E este forma-se a partir do radical da 1ª pessoa do singular do presente do indicativo. De (eu) *cant*(*o*) temos *que eu cant**e**, tu cant**es**, ele cant**e**, nós cant**emos**, vós cant**eis**, eles cant**em***. Isto é radical *cant* + desinência tempo-modo *e*, e o resto é desinência pessoa-número. Nos verbos em -*er* e -*ir* a única diferença é que a desinência tempo-modo é *a* em vez de *e*: *que tu vend**as**, que nós part**amos***, etc. Que é a partir da 1ª pessoa do singular e não das outras só se nota quando há irregularidades: *eu ou**ç**o, tu ou**v**es, ele ou**v**e*, mas *que tu ou**ç**as, ele ou**ç**a*, etc.

Isto vem explicado na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* do Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014, p. 489-90).